# What is the reason PowerPC processors are so popular among switch manufacturers?

Tags: cisco, routing, switch

I noticed that many companies that manufacture switches including Cisco, Avaya and Extreme Networks use processors that use PowerPC architecture.

However they are inferior as speed to Intel and AMD and other x86 architecture processors. Why are PPC processors STILL so popular?

Comment: Inferior in what?

Comment: @JFL to x86 based processors in terms of speed.

Comment: You keep asking questions but never accept any answers.

Comment: @yoyo_fun yes but my question was aimed to make you think about the different aspects involved. A processor is not simply better than another one. It is better at something. Think about power consumption, thermal dissipation, reliability and cost for example. Efficiency in doing some specific tasks is more important than pure speed when that speed is not needed.

Comment: @JFL I understand what you say. However for this purpose I think there may be some reasons that I do ont yet understand and I am thinking maybe the software is not yet optimized for x86 processors.

Comment: Actually, IBM sells Linux-based PowerPC servers that are more powerful than your standard Intel or AMD processors. To get anywhere close, you would need to look at the Intel Xeon line. The x86/x64 architecture is actually very old, and it is very general purpose for desktop-type applications. Think about ARM. Pound for pound, ARM outperforms Intel, and it is optimized for embedded applications, much like routers and switches. I think you may see that used in more routers and switches in the future than Intel desktop processors.

Comment: As this question seems to be generating a lot of opinions, I'm voting to close.  The only definitive answers would come from the switch manufacturers.  Everyone else is just speculating.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPC processors are based in RISC architecture and x86 processors are based on CISC architecture.

The main advantage of RISC vs. CISC is that RISC executes its instruction in lower cycles (most of the cases, one cycle) than CISC.

In a switch the most critical task is to move frames coming in through a port to another one to let it out. To achieve this, part of the frame is inspected to know the source MAC, destination MAC and VLAN ID and the the frame is moved from one buffer to another one. It's a typical I/O operation.

As a RISC processor is able to achieve each task in a single CPU cycle, it will be faster forwarding frames than a CISC processor.

The CISC processor, because its own complexities will use more CPU cycles to forward frames.

It doesn't mean that RISC is a far superior architecture than CISC. It means that RISC is better in a single task environment as network switches or routers.

Comment: IIn ALL professional switches, the switching is NOT done by the switch processor, but by a special circuit built for switching like those that broadcom makes. So your explanation is not correct. However switches still need to have a CPU to run complex protocols like STP, OSPF, EIGRP and for that most switches still use POWER PC processors when they can use an Intel one better. And those who have Intel are actually faster.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to the answers already present:

There is a large number of PPC-based SoCs on the market with exactly those features you'd need for a network device: integrated MAC, serial/USB console, hardware watchdog, ... Some years ago, MIPS used to be very popular but due to (I guess) performance benefits, PPC has mostly captured that market. I think that we're going to see a strong swing towards ARM in a few years.

x86(-64)-based SoCs have only a few of those features, therefore require additional hardware on-board, and are generally more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The exact reasons are known only to the manufacturers, and everyone else is just speculating. But its worth understanding that there are more reasons than performance.

The OpenPOWER Foundation exists to make that architecture freely available to customize. Intel does no such thing, so you are at their mercy when it comes to using the x86 platform.

Large compute customers buy in volume and can drive economies of scale. Maybe not Intel's unit shipped, but enough to provide competition in the commodity CPU market.

Linux runs on POWER already, if that is the OS platform. Other code can be ported to it as well. If Intel independence is desirable, why not?